# Get email addresses from database and send it to all addresses

Tags: php, html

I am new at PhP and trying to write a code that will get all emails from table in db and wrtie them into BCC field in email client(I am using Outlook). 
Fisrt I have created HTML code. For ex, If selected value is Partneri, then I want do get all emails from table where category is Partner.

```
<select name="email">
<option value="Uposlenik"> Uposlenici  <br/>
<option value="Partner"> Partneri  <br/>
<option value="Limari Montazeri"> Limari montažeri  <br/>
<option value="Gradjevinske firme"> Građevinske firme <br/> 
<option value="Krovopokrivacke firme"> Krovopokrivačke firme <br/>
<option value="Preradzivaci lima"> Preradživači lima <br/>
<option value="Limarske radionice"> Limarske radionice  <br/>
<option value="Stovarista-Trgovci"> Stovarišta-Trgovci
</select>
```

After that I have created php file, and I got no errors. The result I got is only selected value nothnig else shows up.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="***"; // username
$password="***"; // password
$database="***"; // Database name
$tbl_name="clanovi"; // Table name

$link=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("$database");
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('db is not selected : ' . mysql_error());
}
$kategorija=$_POST['email'];
//check post
echo $kategorija;

$query= "SELECT  `EMAIL` FROM `clanovi` WHERE `KATEGORIJA`='$kategorija'";

$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Error, query failed!");
mysql_close($link);

$row=1;
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
$bccfield="Bcc:".mysql_result($result,0,"email");
while($row<$numrows)
{
$email=mysql_result($result, $row,"email");
$bccfiled="," .$email;
$row++;
Print "<a href=mailto:test@test.com?bcc=".$bccfield." /> "  ; 
}
$bccfield .="\r\n";
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: For future reference don't paste your username and password!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small glitch in your code. It should be `$bccfiled.="," .$email;`, note the `.` before the `=`, otherwise you overwrite the variable content in every iteration of the loop. But even better style would be to store the addresses in an array and `implode()` them afterwards like this: `implode(',',$bccfields)`.

So the lower part of your script should go something like this:

```
<?php
// ...

$query= "SELECT  `EMAIL` FROM `clanovi` WHERE `KATEGORIJA`='$kategorija'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Error, query failed!");

while(FALSE!==($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
  $bccfields[] = $row['EMAIL'];
}
echo sprintf("<a href=mailto:test@test.com?bcc=%s />\n", 
             urlencode(implode(',',$bccfields))); 
?>
```

Note that I have not tested this, just typed it down. But you should get the idea when you study it.

Comment: There are many, many issues in the script you have to solve. We cannot sort that all out for you. All we can try is to point you into the right direction. Take a look at the script snippet I added in my answer, that should lead you into the right direction.

Comment: arkascha thank you so much. you put me on ne right track and I have solved the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
mysql_result($result,0,"EMAIL");
                    .....^
```

instead of

```
mysql_result($result,0,"email");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start from `$row=0;` instead of `$row=1;`. Otherwise you will ignore the last row retrieved from DB.